# Error: Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: files, convert, gis

I want to convert MODIS HDF files into a NetCDF format in Ubuntu 14.04. I have not compiled the NCO operators with large file size capability and I am getting the following error:

```
ncks: nc4file.c:2696: NC4_open: Assertion `0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I have used these commands for performing the conversion:

```
~$ ncpdq --hdf_upk -P xst_new MOD05_L2.A2000243.2000.005.2006265220542.hdf modis.nc
~$ ncks --hdf4 /home/nghajarnia/MOD05_L2.A2000243.2000.005.2006265220542.hdf /home/nghajarnia/MODIS.nc
```

What must I do?

Comment: Have you looked here http://hdfeos.org/software/h4cflib.php you can get a binary file of the converter and make it executable and run in a terminal. I don't know enough about the subject to explane any more